# In Hibernate, is it better to return a single Object or a List<T> with only one element?

Tags: hibernate

Say I have class `Foo` and I have a `FooRepository` class with a method `select()`.

The `select()` method returns a `List<Foo>` collection of objects.

Now, I want a `select_one()` method that always returns a single object.  Is it best to return type `Foo` or `List<Foo>` with only **ONE** item in the list?  I'm speaking of performance and best practices.

Thanks

Comment: Performance-wise, there's no way this will be a bottleneck. Make it work, and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance-wise it's always better to return a single object.

But, from a design perspective, it really depends on the code that consumes your class. If you want to make a design decision that all methods should return lists, the consumer code could always write code like this:

```
List<Foo> listOfObjects = yourClassInstance.select();

// or 

List<Foo> listOfObjects = yourClassInstance.select_one();

foreach(Foo foo in listOfObjects)
{
    // process the selected objects..
}
```

So, it's really up to you, depending on what you care most about.

But keep in mind that a List has overhead because internally it always creates an array of type T, and other ancillary members. This becomes important if you expect consumers to be calling the code which creates a *list-of-one* many times since it will create many lists and so it will use up more memory and may be slower.